# Custom table field not updating in magento

Tags: php, magento, checkbox

I have created a custom table for my custom module. Data is saving properly in table. But the problem is that after changing one field name that field is not being updated. I have used checkbox for that field. Also before updating field name field was updating only for first time. I don't know that problem is with checkbox field or changed name of field.

Comment: I have already disabled the cache from admin panel.

Comment: Please logout from admin and again login also rename the var folder name.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: can you show me your code how you update field ?

Comment: Now field is updating using  $model->setData('trusetd_seller', $postData['trusetd_seller']);  code. but updating only once.perhaps this is problem with cehckbox.